# REST API Request should be client side or server side?

Tags: php, ajax, api, rest, curl

As a example :

There is examination result validation API and there is a another web application which is use that api as a service. According to that api response(if success) user can enter the site or not

To do that I have a problem with basics,
I came with two options(There may be lot :) any good one is accepted ! )

**01).** Call the API using cross domain AJAX request and and according to the response. Send another request to web app, server script and create a session

```
$.get("http://api.resultval.com/v1/",
   {index_no : no,subject : sub,grade : grade},function(response_msg){
       obj = JSON.parse(response_msg);
       if(obj.msg.valid){
       // results validated marked as validated result on user cv   
       }
   }
);
```

**02).** Instead of sending AJAX request to API send user inserted results to the server side and using server side scripts call the API using *guzzle* library

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->get('http://api.resultval.com/v1/'.Input::get('index_no').'/'.Input::get('subject').'/'.Input::get('grade'));
            if($response->json()['msg']==='verified'){
             // results validated marked as validated result on user cv   
            }
```

What is the best approach ? How About Security ? I think second one is good ! but I still thinking about there is a method to do it in client side ?

Comment: Do you speak about something like a login? So that the called API decides if the user may have access or nor depending on the transmitted data?

Comment: @KhorneHoly Yeh that is my question !

Comment: @Tech-Sira 
I prefer your second solution. Is better to call your API to the server side, users don't need to know that you're calling an api, and with AJAX, they can know your API URL and datas sent (with developpers tools in your browser).

Comment: edited the question and  add specific libraries to do the task !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing your solution using [JWT](http://jwt.io/):

JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact URL-safe means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties. The claims in a JWT are encoded as a JSON object that is digitally signed using JSON Web Signature (JWS)

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather choose to do this server side because of the following reasons:

1. JavaScript could be manipulated by the User. The Ajax requests could be toxic because of bad changes within the JS code trying to reach a security breach.
2. On the ServerSide you have much better options to log the calls that are send by a certain user and do actions based on the results that are comming from the API. Maybe one day you need to do expensive operations based on the results you're getting.
3. The less the user knows, the better it is. Your users don't need to know what services you're exactly calling. At least they musn't know the API Urls and the data you send to the API directly (what would be possible with developertools or traffic sniffers)
4. You can't gurantee the security of a possible third party API, but you can for your own systems. If the user would have the possibility to track down the API you're calling with the data sent and the exact URLs the user could try to attack this API. While you don't know if the API is safe enough to withstand such an attack, you could know that your system does. Also you can instantly update your project if an attack or a security breach is happening. You can't say when this would happen in an third Party project. I think this is one of the most important points to think of!